# Reading sunnat prayers and its importance

Tags: salat, practical-islam, sunnah

I have heard some people said that sunnat prayers are a must after each/after each salah. What is the ruling about reading sunnat and why people says that reading Jummah (friday prayer) Sunnat and Maghrib is a must?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sunnah prayers are important because they [make up for any deficiencies](https://sunnah.com/tirmidhi/2/266) in the Fard prayers we offer. Sunnah prayers are broken down into two categories. The first are the **Sunnah Muakkadah** (high emphasis). Since the Prophet (ﷺ) consistently used to perform the Sunnah Muakkadah prayers (and never left them without reason), Muslims should also regularly perform these. These include Sunnahs of Fajr, Maghrib, etc. The second are **Sunnah Ghair Muakkadah** (no emphasis). There's no blame if these are skipped, because the Prophet (ﷺ) at times did not offer these. Below is a convenient list of prayer classifications [(source).](https://www.albalagh.net/kids/understanding_deen/Salat.shtml)

- **Fajr**: 2 Sunnah [Muakkadah], 2 Fard
- **Zuhr**: 4 Sunnah [Muakkadah], 4 Fard, 2 Sunnah [Muakkadah], 2 Nafl
- **Asr**: 4 Sunnah [Ghair Muakkadah], 4 Fard
- **Maghrib**: 3 Fard, 2 Sunnah [Muakkadah], 2 Nafl
- **Isha**:4 Sunnah [Ghair Muakkadah], 4 Fard, 2 Sunnah [Muakkadah], 2 Nafl, 3 Witr, 2 Nafl

Let me know if you have any further questions.

السلام عليكم ورحمة الله وبركاته

Comment: U mentioned Nafl, can u also mention it. What r they?

Comment: Nafl prayers are totally optional prayers that Islam singled out particularly as virtuous and rewarding. It's up to the Muslim if he wants to pray them or not but to do so is highly rewarding and to not do so does not involve any sin. Totally voluntary.

Comment: What about friday prayer?

Comment: Witr is mu’akkadah as well.